# Jython WLST using python threading module (Weblogic 10)

Tags: multithreading, weblogic, jython, wlst

## Environment

- Weblogic 10
- Sun Java
- HP UX

## Goal

Restart all managed instances with all clusters in a rolling restart fashion. Would like the different clusters to restart concurrently

## Question

Is there a way to use Jython's threading module to do multiple WLST actions at the same time?

## Attempted Approach

In one script I have classes for both cluster and server instance. A cluster has a list of server instances. There is a method on the cluster object to loop through its list of servers and restart them one by one if the cluster is healthy. I have tried passing this method into a thread like so:

```
Thread(target=lambda: cluster.managedRestart()).start()
```

But I receive an error
`TypeError: can't set arbitrary attribute in java instance: target`

## Ideas

Break out the managed restart code into a seperate file and use `execfile()` to call it from within a thread

### Does anyone else have any ideas / suggestions / experience?

Comment: Hi wmarbut, did you resolve your threading solution? If yes how did you fixed it. Your solution could save my reinventing wheel. Please share your learning on this...

Comment: @PavanWLA It has been several years, but I believe that I never got a solution that I was happy with. The Jython API is certainly not thread safe. I've forgotten the issue that I had with the answer below. Sorry to not be of more help

Answer (score 4):

I don't think threads are to be used explicitly to start the managed servers in parallel. Following code will start all the clusters in parallel. `block='false'` will [not block](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24490/reference.htm#autoId332) the control at the start command which means the start command will be issued and immediately the next command which is starting another cluster is executed. Therefore all the clusters can be started in parallel. Same goes with `shutdown` [command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24490/reference.htm#autoId328) as well.

```
connect(username='weblogic', password='weblogic1', url='t3://localhost:7001')
clusterList = ls('/Clusters', returnMap='true')
for cluster in clusterList :
    start(cluster, 'Cluster', block='false')
```